# Aligning third view under two views with variable height

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

Autolayout question.

How can I place "C" view under "A" and "B" but I don't know which view "A" or "B" will be higher? I'm interested only in storyboard solution without using stack views. I want that "C" is placed 8 pt under the higher view "A" or "B". Both views "A" and "B" are aligned to the upper layout guide. How should I setup constraints for it? See image attached:

[image]

Comment: I asked about no code solution. I can program any constraints in my code depending on the calculated height of view A and B but that is no point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the priority of constraint to resolve this issue without having to include any extra view into the hierarchy.

Required Constraints: -
C -> A vertical spacing : `>= 8` with priority **required(1000)**
C -> B vertical spacing : `=8` with priority **high(750)**

Comment: Great solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed A and B in another view , make that views height dependent on A and B, and then set distance from that view to C